# XmlElement equivalent for ReadContentAs

Tags: c#, xmldocument, xmlreader

I'm trying to change my the `XmlReader` I'm using to an `XmlDocument`, but some methods don't seem to exist. I am looking for an equivalent for `XmlReader.ReadContentAs` and `XmlReader.ReadElementContentAs`.

```
Type myType;

if(myType == typeof(Boolean) || myType == typeof(Double))
{
    object myvalue = _cReader.ReadElementContentAs(myType, null);
}

// should become:
if(myType == typeof(Boolean) || myType == typeof(Double))
{
    object myvalue = xmlElement.ParseAnything(myType);
}
```

I'm not only doing this with `Boolean`, but there could be multiple types that can be read in this manner. It could be that `myType` is a `Single` or `Double` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply parse [XmlElement.InnerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to specific type :

```
bool mybool = Boolean.Parse(myXmlElement.InnerText);
```

**UPDATE :**

you can use [Convert.ChangeType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to parse string from Xml to given `Type` variable :

```
Type myType;
if(myType == typeof(Boolean) || myType == typeof(Double))
{
    object myvalue = Convert.ChangeType(xmlElement.InnerText, myType);
}
```

Comment: Boolean.Parse is specific and I want it to be dynamic for any type. Just like ReadElementCOntentAs does.

Comment: Simply change `Boolean.Parse()` with `OtherType.Parse()` when you need to read as other type. How dynamic you meant? isn't `ReadElementContentAs()` also require you to specify the type at compile time?

Comment: I've changed my example. I don't want to write a new line for each type that it could be if it's simple primitive. I'm really looking for an equivalent of ReadElementContentAs.

Comment: `XmlDocument` has different approach from `XmlReader`, so we can't just looking for exact equivalent method. Check my update, there is a general .NET function (not specific from `XmlDocument`) to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I you change the XmlReader - why not change it to XDocument (which is far more simple than XmlDocument).

Regard your question, if I understand you, you just need the `Value` property